# How to start (Register) service on android boot (Start up)?

Tags: java, android, class, service

Am new to android, I would like to develop an app which can receive SMS and process the message.

I have taken a look around the web on how to receive an SMS and bellow is the code am attempting to use.

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String R_Message;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); //---get the SMS message passed in---
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
            String msg_from;
            if (bundle != null) {
                //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                try {
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                        String msgBody = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                    }
                    return;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //Log.d("Exception caught",e.getMessage());
                    R_Message = "No message received";
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the code i found that it can start a service so that my app can be working on background

```
public class SMSService extends IntentService {

  /**
   * A constructor is required, and must call the super IntentService(String)
   * constructor with a name for the worker thread.
   */
  public SMSService() {
      super("SMSService ");
  }
  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
      // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
      // For our sample, we just sleep for 5 seconds.
      try {
          Thread.sleep(5000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // Restore interrupt status.
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }
  }
}
```

> ref: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

I created file(s) SmsListener.java and SMSService.java in manifest i do have

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsListener">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

Permission:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

**But i don't know how to call the above two java processes and where to call them so i can verify the app is receiving SMS and it ll continue even when closed.**

Note: My app will have two services which needs to be working every-time on background please show me how to add the second service.

Any help is greatly apprenticed thanks

Comment: service is added in Manifest file by <service> tag

Comment: I added this <service android:name=".SMSService"/> but i cant see on the service list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observe the service was suppose to be started within one of my activities as follow

> ```
>             Intent intent = new Intent(this, SMSservice.class);
>             startService(intent);
> ```

This has made it possible for the service to start.

Answer (score 1):

As receivers are already declared in manifest file 
SmsListener class will be automatically triggered when ever an message is received 
you can process this info in smslistner

for more info refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html